# Как отсортировать значение массива по значению из словаря

Tags: python

У меня есть массив:

```
[{"name": "123", "age": 10}, {"name": "321", "age": 15}, {"name": "213", "age": 6}]
```

И надо сделать так чтобы вывелось значение `name` того, у кого самое большое значение `age`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = [{"name": "123", "age": 10}, {"name": "321", "age": 15}, {"name": "213", "age": 6}]
print(max(a, key=lambda x: x['age'])['name'])
```

Comment: А как можно отсортировать этот массив?

Comment: Очевидно, использовать `sorted` вместо `max`.